# get left or right position from heading in degrees

Tags: javascript

I am trying to determine if one degree on a circle is closer to the right or the left of another degree on a circle.

For example, if I have a heading of 350 degrees and another heading of 10 degrees, then I need to be able to determine that 10 degrees is to the right of 350 degrees on a circle (because it's only 20 degrees from the right -- as opposed to 340 degrees from the left).

How could this be accomplished?

Comment: From you're question, i suppose the positive direction of the angle is clockwise, is this right?

Comment: *"How could this be accomplished?"* -- use math?!

Answer (score 1):

What you actually need is see if the difference between `deg1` and `deg2` is less then 180 (then deg2 on the right side) or more then it (then deg2 is on the left side

The problem is, that the deg reset at `360`, means the diff between `10` and `350` is 20.. for that you can just add 360 and module by 360.

Like this

```js
function closerSide(deg1, deg2){
  return (360+deg1-deg2)%360 > 180 ? 'deg2 on the right' : 'deg2 on the left'
}
function from180(deg){return Math.abs(180-deg)}

// tests
[[10, 350], [200,220], [30, 50], [350, 10], [180, 50]].forEach(t => console.log(closerSide(...t)))
```

Answer (score 0):

For degrees higher than 180, if you subtract it from 360 then you get the equivalent of a degree under 180.

Then you can compare their difference to find out on which side the 2nd degree is from the 1e degree.

```js
function degreeRightOrLeft (degree1, degree2) {
    let d1 = (degree1 > 180) ? 360 - degree1 : degree1;
    let d2 = (degree2 > 180) ? 360 - degree2 : degree2;
    let diff = d2 - d1;
    return (diff > 0) ? 'Left'
         : (diff < 0) ? 'Right'
         : (diff === 0) ? 'Same'
         : undefined;
}

degrees = [[10, 20], [350, 340], [0, 360], [10,340], [350, 20], [90, 270], [160, 200], [180, 160]];

degrees.forEach(d => { console.log(`(${d[0]}, ${d[1]}) : ${degreeRightOrLeft(d[0], d[1])}`)} )
```